# Carregar uma variavel de um arquivo com modulo. Django/Python

Tags: python, django, openpyxl, módulo-python

Olá, me chamo marvin, sou iniciante na área e estou com um problema na hora de dar um 'POST' uma variável de um 'arquivo.py' para meu servidor local Django. Eu utilizo um modulo chamado 'openpyxl' que serve para carregar uma tabela de um excel(.XLS) e salvar todas as informações dentro de um vetor.
Meu código funciona perfeitamente, verifiquei se já está instalado o modulo e pesquisei bastante sobre mas não encontrei a solução.
Eu utilizo a versão do django 1.11.17 e a mais recente em python

Esse é o erro que tenho no prompt de comando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu codigo em python é esse:

```
´´´´
from openpyxl import load_workbook

bd1 = list(range(1, 300))

wb = load_workbook('BD2.xlsx')


sh = wb['Planilha1']


coluns = sh.max_column
rows = sh.max_row


word = input('Search: ')


for i in range(1, rows + 1):
    for j in range(1, coluns + 1):
        c = sh.cell(i, j)

        if str(c.value).lower().find(word.lower()) != -1:
            cont = 0
            cont = cont + 1
            for x in range(1, coluns + 1):
                bd1[cont] = sh.cell(i, x).value
                print(bd1[cont])
```

Minha view onde ele não consegue ler meu 'arquivo.py':

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .Excel import bd1
from .Excel2 import bd2


# Create your views here.

def homepage(request):
    return render(request, 'bin/index.html', {'cont2': bd1, 'cont': bd2})
´´´´´´
```

Settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'app',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'server.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'server.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Obrigado pela atenção e agradeço desde já! https://github.com/marvinbraescher/Excelfile

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi (se não estiver correto diga me), O código que importa o openpyxl ,nela existe uma função input, sera uma pesquisa no arquivo BD2.xlsx, ao chamar esse modulo sera feita uma pesquisa de alguma informação.

Esse modulo foi importado para a views no django, o msmo não encontra esse modulo e sua terefa não é concluida.

O django nesse teu código não vai interagir com o input no outro modulo.

Poderia ser assim.

Pegar um campo no html "search"
e essa variavel pode ser passada para o xls em vez do "word = input('Search: ')".

**Exemplo**

def searchxls(request):

```
form = searchForms(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    det = form.data
    search= det["search"]
    print("Item pesquisado %s"%search)
     .....Inicio código xls
    #word = input('Search: ') trocar por...
    word = search
     ...Fim do código xls
      passando o resultado para um dic e direcionado para o render
```

Na pagina html um loop (for) mostrar todos os resultados